# Best way to create/append new dictionary to json, so that it can be converted to df easily later in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm trying to save data from a simple dictionary to a json file and trying to read it later for downstream processing. Problem is I'm able to save data but I'm unable to convert it to python data frame later.

Sample data and code:

```
def new_data(a, b, c, d):
    info = dict()
    info['A'] = a
    info['B'] = b
    info['C'] = c
    info['D'] = d
    return info

cat1 = new_data("Python", "2", "old", "not compatible")
cat2 = new_data("Python", "3", "new", "compatible")

file_path = "Programs.json"
with open(file_path, 'a') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(cat1))
with open(file_path, 'a') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(cat2))

with open(file_path, "r") as file:
    data = json.load(file)
```

I'm receiving following error:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 61 (char 60)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to append to a JSON file, might I suggest linewise JSON:

```
with open(file_path, "a") as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(cat1) + "\n")  # note \n = line break
```

When reading this file, you need to read and decode it line by line:

```
docs = []
with open(file_path, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        doc = json.loads(line)
        print(doc)
        docs.append(doc)
```

Comment: how does that work if I json dump:  `d = {0: "one\ntwo\nthree"}` ? will the "inline" \n be converted to something non-linebreaking by json.dump() ?

Comment: JSON supports a backslash escaping syntax; that also covers newlines. `json.dumps({"a":"b\nc"})` will thus result in `{"a": "b\\nc"}`, which is safe for `for line in f` (or `str.split("\n")` for that matter).

Answer (score 1):

You are creating invalid json if you simply append to an existing json file more json data - you would need to load the existing file, put the object into a list with your new object and then write the list of objects to the file:

```
import json

def new_data(a, b, c, d):
    info = dict()
    info['A'] = a
    info['B'] = b
    info['C'] = c
    info['D'] = d
    return info

cat1 = new_data("Python", "2", "old", "not compatible")
cat2 = new_data("Python", "3", "new", "compatible")

file_path = "another_Programs.json"

with open(file_path,"w") as f:
    f.write(json.dumps([cat1,cat2])) # store them as list of json dicts

with open(file_path,"r") as f: 
    print(json.load(f))
```

Output:

```
[{'A': 'Python', 'B': '2', 'C': 'old', 'D': 'not compatible'}, 
 {'A': 'Python', 'B': '3', 'C': 'new', 'D': 'compatible'}]
```

The error tells you as much: there is additional data after reading some of it:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: **Extra data: line 1 column 61** (char 60)
```

A file content of `{'A': 'Python', 'B': '2', 'C': 'old', 'D': 'not compatible'}{'A': 'Python', 'B': '3', 'C': 'new', 'D': 'compatible'}` is no valid json.

Comment: Thanks @Patrick. The format in which I'm trying to save is not a complete json format. I just created empty list and then tried to add contents to the list. I was able to manage for sample data, but If I have millions of records then, reading the json from disk to memory and then writing it back to disk is not a good solution. Is there any other way that I can do in python with json without completely reading the file into memory.

Comment: Not if you want to use json.load() to restore them. You cold of course write a function that simply appends one json object to your file, then writes ******************************************** into it. If you want to load that file you would load from ***************** to ******************** , strip the *********** and json.load() the things between it into one object. But what then? if you want to maniputlate the 263475 object in your file you would still have to read in all 263474 before, then manpulate 1 then read the rest, and then save all again. I would use a database for that - not

Comment: file based json - and any such implementation is too broad a topic for SO. Maybe investigate in direction of file based databases like sqlite

Comment: if your data does not contain \n you could also use \n as "divider" between valid json.dump()ed objects - still, file basedmanipulating somthing in between w/o loading all im memory sucks. @Lufy

Comment: I want to use json.load() to restore them when ever I need to do some manipulation on the data. You are correct, may be json is not the correct solution here if I need to save large data. I'll look into databases.. Thanks for your comments. really helpful